# How to perform multiple save function on tabcontrol C#

Tags: c#, save, tabcontrol

I''m devoloping a multi tabbed notepad application. How do I perform a save all function on all the tabs on the application without opening a SaveFileDialog after I save the tabs. The method shown below works but it opens a SaveFileDialog for all the tabs.

```
string strfilename;
RichTextBox rtb = null;

private void saveAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
        foreach (TabPage page in pages)
        {
            if (rtb != null)

            {

                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

                    rtb.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }
        }
    }
```

I tried it like this as well but only last saved tab gets saved

```
  private void saveAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
        foreach (TabPage page in pages)
        {
            rtb = page.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;

            if (rtb != null)

            {
                    rtb.SaveFile(strfilename, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }
        }
    }
```

This is my individual save function

```
  public void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog();
        sv.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            GetRichTextBox().SaveFile(sv.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        this.Text = sv.FileName;
        strfilename = sv.FileName;
        autosave(sv.FileName);
    }
```

Comment: You need to change `strfilename` for each iteration, otherwise all tabs will overwrite the same file. This is why it appears like only the last file is saved.

Comment: @VisualVincent how can I do that ?

Comment: You need to keep track of the file paths for each tab (you could use a [**`List<string>`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) for example). When you "save all" have your code get the file path for the tab that it is currently at, then pass that to the `SaveFile()` method. If a tab has never been saved to a file before you just open a `SaveFileDialog` for it.

Comment: How to get the file path of tab? Is there a predefined method available?

Comment: Whenever you open a new tab add an entry to the list. If this is a new document add an empty string, if it's an existing file add its path. Whenever you close a tab you remove its entry from the list by calling `yourList.RemoveAt(index here);` - where `index here` is the index of the current tab. And whenever you save check if the path is empty, and if that is the case display a `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: _"How to get the file path of tab?"_ - You can't. As I said **you** have to keep track of it by yourself (refer to above comment).

Comment: @VisualVincent , yes, that is correct. _Why would the application keep track of it for you, if you aren't telling it how?_

Answer (score 0):

**Though this is old,**

You can save the file name for the tab with it's **Name,**

e.g.

```
Tabpage tb = new TabPage();
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

tb.Name = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName); // <--- 'ofd' is the OpenFileDialog
tb.Controls.Add(rtb);
tb.Text = Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName); // <--- This sets the tab's text to the file's name, rather than the full path.
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
```

You can put that snippet of code into the part where you actually open a file.

So, when the user (Or *you*) presses the **Save All** button, this snippet of code should be used:

```
foreach (TabPage tb in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    if (File.Exists(tb.Name))
    {
         File.WriteAllText(tb.Name, ((RichTextBox)tb.Controls[0]).Text); // <--- You can optionally save the RTF!
    }
    else if (!File.Exists(tb.Name))
    {
       saveFileDialog(sender, e);
    }
}
```

`saveFileDialog(sender, e)` is the Link to your 'Save As' dialog, so that the user may save the individual files that either were deleted and don't exist anymore, or files that never existed all together. (Like if the user presses 'New', and it creates a new tab with a `RichTextBox` in it, the name would not exist as a file.)

For your 'New Tab' button,

```
TabPage tb = new TabPage();
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

tb.Name = "New.Txt";
tb.Text = "New.Txt";
tb.Controls.Add(rtb);

tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
```

Optionally, you can create an integer to watch how many 'New.Txt' are created, and instead of it displaying 'New.Txt', it would display 'New*5.Txt' if there were already four tabs before it. (I won't go too far into that.)

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Like you said, if I created an integer to watch the amount of 'New.Txt' that existed in the TabControl, then if I created a new Tab with the 'New Tab' button, I would do `pageCount++;`? And when I remove a tab, e.g. pressing the red 'X' button that I create with OwnerDraw, I would do `pageCount--;`? Also, to prevent the TabControl from holding less than ONE tab, I would do `if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count > 1) { //remove the requested tab }` and if the `TabPages.Count` was not more than 1, it would not remove any?

Comment: ...Yes. `if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count >1)` means if the `TabControl` has **more** than 1 `TabPages`. `>` means more, `<` means less.